# Convert Julian date in date

Tags: r, date

I have the following july date format YYYYJJJ, example: 2019001. I am trying to convert this date into YYYY-MM-DD format, example: 2019-01-01

Answer (score 0):

We need `%j` in the `format`

```
as.Date(as.character(v1), "%Y%j")
#[1] "2019-01-01"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- 2019001
```